# Django: Remove dependency between apps in a project

Tags: python, django

I have a django project. I have created 2 apps(app1 and app2) under the project.
Each app has its own urls.py and views.py.
Settings.py is under the project folder.

What I want to do is: 
When I edit the views.py file for app1. And if I save the file with an incorrect indentation.

It brings down app2 as well.

I want to make them independent, so that no matter what change I do local to app1 it should not affect app2.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a new Django project, and move app2 to that project.

Comment: I want to avoid doing that as I dont want to run multiple projects. The apps do have some common functionality

Comment: @user1426777: Apps aren't independent. A syntax error in a file in one app will affect the entire project.